# Anchor links getting a white border or space

Tags: css

I am trying to make a menu with slanted ends and buttons with triangular ends in my project. But I am ending up with some white spaces in firefox and ie.

I have taken code which you can see on this page:

[SOURCE](http://bgwebagency.com/2015/11/25/create-fancy-button-with-css/)

[image]

I.e.

[image]

But in chrome there is no such space and just looks fine.

[image]

My work can be seen at this website:

[thejobupdates.com/pt/devos](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/devos)

Please help me out to remove the unwanted white spacings.

I also have a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/hwwzt5vq/) here for you guys to edit.

CSS:

```
     #heroTab li > a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            line-height: 52px;
            padding: 0 8px;
            color:#fff; 
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-family:'open_sansregular', sans-serif;
            font-size:15px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            background: #243276;
        }
    #heroTab li > a:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 26px solid #243276; 
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
#heroTab li > a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 26px solid #243276; 
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the margin left/right on the tabs to -1px, e.g.

```
#heroTab li > a {
...
    margin:10px -1px;
...
}
```

This will cover up the apparent gap. I think this is a rendering issue with angles, so you have to overlap them by 1px to get rid of it. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hwwzt5vq/1/).

Comment: I tried that. Thanks for it. But is this the correct solution? I mean there is no space when I view this in chrome. So, I guess this is a browser related issue. And there might be a solution to this instead of overlapping.

Comment: if there is no other solution then definitely yours margin trick will do the job. anyways i have already used this trick for my project. but still would like to know if it can be solved on browser basis.

Comment: It's not an especially pretty solution but there's also nothing wrong with it in my eyes. Overlapping slightly to cover up browser differences seems like the only solution to me. I am seeing the gap on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari by the way. Shouldn't interfere with functionality of your site in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Use this style to fix issue in firefox & Ie

```
#heroTab li {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 51px;
}
```